# Should two DFAs be complete before making an intersection of them?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, closure-properties

In the slides given by my teacher, the third automaton is the product of the first two:

[image: Three DFAs]

I tried to do the product myself by doing the transition table of both automata at the same time. I got stuck when I realised that the second automaton has no transition from state $2$ with $a$ as input symbol, thus the automaton should halt at that moment. In the third automaton, I can see there is no transition with input symbol $a$ in any of the states that have $2$ in (sorry for the bad expression, don't know how else to say it).

So when doing the transition table of the two automata, if there is no transition, should I just ignore it like in the 3rd automaton? Or would it be wise to complete the automaton?

Comment: If you allow for incomplete automata then that is indeed how it should work. The transition "a" is forbidden in states 02 and 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, a deterministic finite-state automaton $(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ must have a total transition function: For every $q \in Q$ and $a \in \Sigma$, $\delta(q,a)$ must be defined.

Automaton no. 2 is not well-defined and for this reason it makes no sense to apply the product construction to the two automata given in your question.

(A note on grammar: The singular form is *automaton*, the plural is *automata* – we cannot speak of "an automata" or "two automatas".)

Comment: So basically the third automaton is complete non-sense?

Comment: @JohnMayne Probably your teacher just forgot a transition in his slides. You should ask him.

Comment: "By definition" -- not every definition. You can reasonably leave out transitions, provided you adapt the semantics accordingly. (cc @JohnMayne)

Comment: I'd just call the second automaton non-deterministic and act accordingly. That is, a missing transition is a non-match.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you would make 2 deterministic. Would you just add a transition on 'a' from state 2 to a new non-accepting state that transitions on 'a' and 'b' back to itself?

Comment: How would one make automaton 2 deterministic? There is no unique answer to this – it depends entirely on the language that you would like the automaton to recognize.

Comment: It's a commom notational shortcut to ommit dead-end states. They are obviously there, if this is the convention adopted. This is a pointless argument.

Comment: @HansHüttel: We already know what language it recognizes; that was Jan Dvorak's point. It's true that there are arbitrarily many DFAs that would accept that language, but Shufflepants' proposal is the simplest and most sensible.

Answer (score 9):

> So when doing the transition table of the two automata, if there is no transition, should I just ignore it like in the 3rd automaton?

If there is no transition in one of the automata, then that one won't accept the input word. Therefore, the automaton for the intersection should not accept either; not having a transition is one way to make sure of that.